# Check if a compressed file is password protected

Tags: php, zip, 7zip, rar

I am developing a portal where users submit some archived samples.I need to check if these samples are password protected compressed files or not. I am able to detect if these files are compressed or not, but i am stuck how to check if the file is password protected or not. Can someone help?
I am using php.

Answer (score 0):

The following is defined in the [RAR technote](http://rescene.wikidot.com/rar-420-technote):

```
   Archive header ( MAIN_HEAD )

HEAD_FLAGS      Bit flags:
2 bytes
                0x0040  - Recovery record present
                0x0080  - Block headers are encrypted
                0x0100  - First volume (set only by RAR 3.0 and later)

   File header (File in archive)

HEAD_FLAGS      Bit flags:
2 bytes
                0x01 - file continued from previous volume
                0x02 - file continued in next volume
                0x04 - file encrypted with password
```

So check for those flags on the blocks.